# Possible to Run Wordpress on EC2/Rackspace Cloud Servers?

Tags: amazon-ec2

Is it possible to run Wordpress on EC2/Rackspace Cloud Servers? What would I have to do in order to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. EC2 and RackSpace virtual servers work the same as the real ones your web host used. WordPress doesn't know and runs exactly the same.